How to group using a like query on column of names
I need to create a datatable of records from a SQL Server table where one column is names that are sometimes misspelled etc. These records are imported by way of a spreadsheet where the data capturer has misread or whatever. In VS I can select all characters after "." for example & do a Like query on that. I don't know how to do that in SQL Server & since these are results from many competitions the same surname will appear many times so once a surname has been grouped & encountered again not to group on it again. for example "van der Merwe", "van de Merwe" could be the same person or different people.
Whilst as a self taught coder & previously helped by reading others questions, I have no idea where to start in this instance. If anyone has encountered & resolved a similar need, I'd really appreciate being pointed in a direction that will ultimately bring me to a solution.

You may look at Jaro-Winkler String Similarity implementations in T-SQL.

You might find the answer I wrote to this question useful.

Let's say you have found a logic, what makes you so sure that John Smith in row 1 is same as John Smith in row 5? If you're only comparing names for some identification purposes, you are already playing a lost game, unless we're talking movie stars

@siggemannen That is one of my issues. Competitors who are registered are allocated a number by which they get identified but there are a lot of ad-hoc entries at each comp as well. I want to establish the ratio & who the ad-hoc is vs registered

@p3consulting While the Jaro-Winkler method looks intimidating to me, I'm going to have a go at seeing if I fully understand what it's doing & try implement something over the next few days. If I get it right I'll post an answer

I've been using an implementation of the Damerau–Levenshtein distance for this purpose for many years. Code for a T-SQL function has been published online. I use a CLR function I wrote that is forty percent faster but I am not in a position to publish the code.

Have you heard about SOUNDEX function ??
screenshot to see , how soundex is used
If you see the above screenshot , both 'van der Merwe' and 'van de Merwe' has same output which is V500 .
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  empId int,
  name varchar(15),
  dept varchar(10)
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(empId,name,dept) VALUES (1, 'van der Merwe', 'Sales');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(empId,name,dept) VALUES (2, 'van de Merwe', 'Accounting');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(empId,name,dept) VALUES (3, 'Ava', 'Sales');

-- fetch 
SELECT *,soundex(name) soundcode FROM EMPLOYEE;


SOUNDEX isn't going to work here, it only considers the first word. 'Which shoes should I wear today' and 'Which toy should I buy?'' will have the same value . db<>fiddle

Also, please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
